# Zend_Db_Table fetchAll and column names

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I'm testing Zen_DB and Zend_DB_Table and I'm facing a problem:

Let's say I've got two tables
table A(id, title)
table B(id, title)

If I write something like

```
$db = $this->getDbTable()->getAdapter();  
$query = "SELECT A.*, B.* FROM A INNER JOIN B on A.id = B.id"  
$stmt = $db->query($query);  
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

each resulting row is like ['id' => value, 'title' => value]

**Question:** How can the fetched rows be like ['A.id' => value, 'A.title' => value', 'B.id' => value, 'B.title' => value'] ?

**Important**: I don't want to modify the database schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your question was answered by this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431391/php-mysql-how-to-resolve-ambiguous-column-names-in-join-operation)