# MySQL: SELECT * FROM table1, table2.... column1 AS newColumnName

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1052

I'm selecting data from two tables. And both of those tables have an `ID` column, and i need both of the `ID` columns returned after executing the `Query`. Is there any way to change the name of the ID column (from the second table i'm selecting from) to something else using AS?

I'm thinking something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table2.id AS newAlias
```

Can I use the WHERE statement like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP & MYSQL: How to resolve ambiguous column names in JOIN operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431391/php-mysql-how-to-resolve-ambiguous-column-names-in-join-operation)

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify the alias for the column in the select list.
e.g:

```
SELECT a.id AS table1_id, b.id AS table2_id, ....
  FROM table1 a, table2 b
 WHERE <YOUR CRITERIA>
```

Comment: Yes, but what if i want all the columns from both tables? I'd get a pretty long and confusing query if i had to name each column from the tables. The query would also break if i decide to add/rename a column.

Comment: @qwerty On the contrary, the query would continue to **work** (i.e. return the same resultset...) if you were to add a column. Renaming columns is a no-go anyway if you want to avoid breaking existing queries.

Comment: Well, they would continue working, but i would have to add the new column manually. Correct? I want to avoid that if it's possible.

Comment: It is always a good idea to actually select only columns application needs from specific query, not '*'.

Comment: @qwerty: SELECT * is almost always a bad idea, as it causes a lot of unnecessary network traffic and uses a larger amount of memory in your application. You should always list the specific columns you want returned, and always use a WHERE clause to limit the number of rows returned to as few as possible. Laziness is not an excuse. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

@qwerty

You can write:

```
SELECT a.*,a.id AS table1_id, b.*,b.id AS table2_id, ....
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE <YOUR CRITERIA>
```