# PHP/mySQL get all column names and create list

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm using this to define the valid keys that can be used to perform a search on my front end:

```
$validKeys = array('gender','marital_status', 'age');
```

The rest of my code works great in that it only accepts keys sent to it in an AJAX call that are in this array.

However, I want to be able to make this list (`'gender','marital_status', 'age'`) dynamic. That is, I'd like to include all of the columns from my table in here so that every column is essentially a valid key. I have about 10-15 depending on the table and I'd rather not hard-code it into each PHP file.

How would I go about getting all the column names in my table and arranging them into this variable? So, I need to get all the names, put them in single quotes and comma separate. Unless there's a way to get them in a proper array and skip the `array` part of defining the `$validkeys` variable.

If I var_dump `$validKeys`, I get this:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "gender"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "marital_status"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "age"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "anglers"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "baseball"
}
```

Any direction would be appreciated.

EDIT: Should have been more explicit that I am using PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a query using the [`DESCRIBE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/describe.html) syntax. That will return all columns to you which you can then place in the array.

```
DESCRIBE `table_name`;
```

Another option is [`SHOW COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/show-columns.html). Either will work for your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

you can try with mysqli's fetch_fields-function.

```
$finfo = $result->fetch_fields();
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php

Answer (score 1):

I should have been a bit more explicit that I am using PDO, so Jay's answer above pointed me in the right direction and I found this answer that gave me the details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7091984/989722

The full code snippet based on my question looks like this:

```
$q = $dbh->prepare("DESCRIBE full_db2");
$q->execute();
$table_fields = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
$validKeys = $table_fields;
```