# How to know which columns have not null constraint in postgres via php?

Tags: php, postgresql, null, constraints

Im trying to build some html input elements via php in order to fill up rows in a postgres table.

I want to add the attribute "required" to some of the html input elements (those that correspond to the columns that have the NOT NULL constraint).

How can I know which columns have that constraint?

Comment: `\d <table name>` in the postgres shell?

Comment: That should work... but how do I do it programmatically?

Comment: Depends on the DB engine you use (PDO, pg_* functions, etc. etc.), but I wonder why would you want to do that during runtime, unless you're building some sort of a DB web editor.

Comment: Im trying to make a web page that gives the user the possibility to add rows to a table.. I expect more columns to be added to the table (with and without the not null contraint, that's why I want to do it programmatically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PDO (and suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428262/php-pdo-get-the-columns-name-of-a-table)), you should be able to pull it off as follows:

```
$q = $dbh->prepare("\d tablename");
$q->execute();
$table_fields = $q->fetchAll();
foreach ($table_fields as $field) {
    if (strpos($field['Modifiers'], 'not null') !== FALSE) {
         // this column ($field['Column']) has a "not null" constraint.
    }
}
```

**Edit**: same if you're dead set on using PostgreSQL PHP extension:

```
$q = pg_query("\d tablename");
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (strpos($row['Modifiers'], 'not null') !== FALSE) {
         // this column ($row['Column']) has a "not null" constraint.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there a way to accomplish it with pg_* functions? or even with SQL commands in psql? Sorry for not being specific...

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the pg_* functions. As for the functions specific to this particular purpose, they don't exist as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Pomm](http://www.pomm-project.org) and it will perform those queries for you to inspect your database with the CLI:

```
$ php vendor/bin/pomm.php pomm:inspect:relation test pika_chu
Relation public.pika_chu
+----+---------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+---------+
| pk | name          | type   | default                                       | notnull | comment |
+----+---------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+---------+
| *  | pika_chu_id   | int4   | nextval('pika_chu_pika_chu_id_seq'::regclass) | yes     |         |
|    | some_data     | int4   |                                               | yes     |         |
|    | nullable_data | bpchar |                                               | no      |         |
+----+---------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+---------+
```