# How to select all column name from a table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have tried to get all column names from a table **Teller**

Function:

```
public function getTableColumns($tables)
{
    return DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT 
                                    COLUMN_NAME, 
                                    DATA_TYPE, 
                                    COLUMN_DEFAULT
                                FROM 
                                    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                WHERE 
                                    table_name = `Teller`'));
}
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can get all columns name by simply doing that...

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

public function getTableColumns($table)
{
    return DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($table);

    // OR

    return Schema::getColumnListing($table);

}
```

Comment: The problem here when doing joins is that you need to prefix the column names with the table name like: $tableName =...; $columns = Schema::getColumnListing($tableName);
        $columns = array_map(function ($elem) use ($tableName) {return $tableName . '.' . $elem;}, $columns);

Comment: Excellent! It's working

Answer (score 26):

**Get Table Name** From Model

```
$product = new Product;
$table = $product->getTable();
print_r($table);
```

**Get Table Column Name** From Model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Product extends Model
{   
    public function getTableColumns() {
        return $this->getConnection()->getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($this->getTable());
    }
}
```

Now you will get all columns of "products" table and **if you need it in controller** then you can get it by following way :

```
 $product = new Product;
 $columns = $product->getTableColumns();
 print_r($columns);
```

Answer (score 7):

Just in-case if you have multiple databases connections, try following:

**Add in the top of your php script**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

**Retrieve anywhere in your code**

**With Database Connection**

```
$columns = Schema::Connection('business')->getColumnListing('users'); // 'business' is your database connection

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($columns);
        exit();
```

**Without Database Connection**

```
$columns = Schema::getColumnListing('users');

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($columns);
    exit();
```

Answer (score 3):

You only need extract the keys from the query response

```
array_keys(json_decode(json_encode($table[0]), true))
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Laravel 6.x this works:

```
                    $db = DB::connection()->getPdo();
                    $rs = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Teller LIMIT 0');
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $rs->columnCount(); $i++) {
                            $col = $rs->getColumnMeta($i);
                            $columns[] = $col['name'];
                    }
                    print_r($columns);
```

The hint here is just to go around eloquent (which should just provide a simple way to do this, but clearly does not) and grab the PDO object and then [use the answer from the same question for straight PDO access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15671366/144364)

This will also work when there is no database selected by replacing 'Teller' with databasename.Teller

HTH,

-ft

Answer (score 3):

Another way from a model using collections.

```php
collect(User::first())->keys();
```

Answer (score 2):

@Eduardo Wallace method has it simplest; just return the first value from the table, strip off the values leaving the keys

```
$T1 = table_name::first();
$table_columns = array_keys(json_decode($T1, true));
```

If you don't need all the columns, strip away unneeded columns, leaving only the ones needed:

```
$needed_columns = array_diff($table_columns, ['unneeded_1', 'unneeded_2']);
```

You can argue the method used, simplest to me anyways!

Answer (score 1):

```
$db = [];
$tables =  DB::select('SHOW TABLES');

    foreach ($tables as $key => $table) {
        $name = $table->Tables_in_app;
        $app[$name] =  DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($name);
    }

return $db;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get an idea with this script

```
    $columns = array();
    foreach(\DB::select("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table") as $column)
    {
       //print_r($column);
        $columns[$column->Field] = '';
    }
  
    return $columns;
```

Answer (score 0):

in **12.17.22**  it's
extremely simple

```
$columns=Schema::getColumnListing('my_table_name');
//e.g. your table's name is 'my_table_name' or 'Teller' or   'posts'
// and then
$fetchedSet= Post::select($columns)->where('sender_id','>',100)->get();
```

And you are done

Answer (score 0):

```
$columns = DB::select("SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name");

//This code will return column array as table defined in database.
return array_column($columns, 'Field');

//This code will return column array asc order of column name.
return Schema::getColumnListing('table_name');
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: You can get all columns name as you defined in database one after one by simply doing first block code.

Comment: You can get all columns array in asc order by doing 2nd return block code

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

getTableColumns((new Model())->getTable());    

function getTableColumns($table){
   return DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($table);
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34693943)

Answer (score -3):

You could simply write:

```
public function getTableColumns($tables)
{
    return DB::select(
        DB::raw('SELECT * FROM `Teller`')
    );
}
```

If you have a `Teller` model you can also use `Teller::all();`

**Update**

To get all column name you can run `SHOW FIELDS Teller`

Comment: Get Column name not get value in each column

Comment: I updated my answer. But there is no Laravel/Eloquent call for that.

Answer (score -4):

You can use this

```
DB::table('table_name')->get();
```

Comment: This is for getting data. The question was for getting column names, which should work even if no data is there.