# How can you include column headers when exporting Eloquent to Excel in Laravel?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

I am trying to allow users to download Excel, using [Laravel Excel](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/) files with product information. My current web route looks like this:

```
Route::get('/excel/release', 'ExcelController@create')->name('Create Excel');
```

My current Export looks like this:

```
class ProductExport implements FromQuery
{
    use Exportable;

    public function __construct(int $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function query()
    {
        return ProductList::query()->where('id', $this->id);
    }
}
```

My current controller looks like this:

```
public function create(Request $request) {

    # Only alowed tables
    $alias = [
        'product_list' => ProductExport::class
    ];

    # Ensure request has properties
    if(!$request->has('alias') || !$request->has('id'))
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['Please fill in the required fields.'])->withInput();

    # Ensure they can use this
    if(!in_array($request->alias, array_keys($alias)))
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['Alias ' . $request->alias . ' is not supported'])->withInput();

    # Download
    return (new ProductExport((int) $request->id))->download('iezon_solutions_' . $request->alias . '_' . $request->id . '.xlsx');
}
```

When I head over to `https://example.com/excel/release?alias=product_list&id=1` this executes correctly and returns an excel file. However, there is no column headers for the rows. The data comes out like so:

```
1   150 1   3       2019-01-16 16:37:25 2019-01-16 16:37:25     10
```

However, this should contain column headers like ID, cost etc... How can I include the column headers in this output?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/mapping.html#adding-a-heading-row) you can change your class to use the `WithHeadings` interface, and then define the `headings` function to return an array of column headers:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class ProductExport implements FromQuery, WithHeadings
{
    use Exportable;

    public function __construct(int $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function query()
    {
        return ProductList::query()->where('id', $this->id);
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return ["your", "headings", "here"];
    }
}
```

This works with all export types (`FromQuery`, `FromCollection`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there a way I can use Eloquent to get the columns in the database dynamically? I'll accept as soon as i can!

Comment: If you're exporting all the columns of the table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37157879/1255289

Comment: how do i must call the headings method in the controller?

Comment: @miken32 Is there any way to pass the array to headings from `query` functions or at least update it there and make it available on headings. Actually, I need to add Headings only if there are data on that column. So, is there any workaround for that?

Comment: It's a function. You can do whatever you want with it @SarojShrestha. Look at the code for the class, it's likely the data is a property you can get to.

Comment: **use Exportable;** seems unnecessary

Answer (score 22):

```
<?php
namespace App\Exports;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use DB;
class LocationTypeExport implements FromCollection,WithHeadings
{
    public function collection()
    {
        $type = DB::table('location_type')->select('id','name')->get();
        return $type ;
    }
     public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'id',
            'name',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: It only worked with :array for me, probably because of a newer version.

Answer (score 9):

You can combine this with `array_keys` to dynamically get your column headers:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class ProductExport implements FromQuery, WithHeadings
{
    use Exportable;

    public function __construct(int $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function query()
    {
        return ProductList::query()->where('id', $this->id);
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return array_keys($this->query()->first()->toArray());
    }
}
```

If you're using it with a collection, you can do so like the following:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class ProductExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        // for selecting specific fields
        //return ProductList::select('id', 'product_name', 'product_price')->get();
        // for selecting all fields
        return ProductList::all();
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return $this->collection()->first()->keys()->toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: When exporting my user table I needed to use: `array_keys($this->collection()->first()->toArray());` even though that’s using `FromCollection` as it’s a Collection of Models.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, so simple and dynamic!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\UserDetails;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class CustomerExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
   
    public function collection()
    {
        return UserDetails::whereNull('business_name')
        ->select('first_name','last_name','mobile_number','dob','gender')
        ->get();
    }

   
    public function headings() :array
    {
        return ["First Name", "Last Name", "Mobile","DOB", "Gender"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Exports;
    
    use App\Models\StudentRegister;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
    
    class StudentExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
    {
        /**
        * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
        */
        public function collection()
        {
           
            return StudentRegister::select('name','fname','mname','gender','language','address')->get();
        }
    
        public function headings(): array
        {
            //Put Here Header Name That you want in your excel sheet 
            return [
                'Name',
                'Father Name',
                'Mother Name',
                'Gender',
                'Opted Language',
                'Corresponding Address'
            ];
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I am exporting from Collections and I wanted to generate headings automatically from the column names. The following code worked for me!

```
public function headings(): array
{
    return array_keys($this->collection()->first()->toArray());
}
```

If you want to manually write the column names return an array with the column names.

And don't forget to implement the **WithHeadings** interface

Thanks @Ric's comment.

Answer (score -1):

This code works for me

```
use App\Newsletter;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class NewsletterExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Subscriber Id',
            'Name',
            'Email',
            'Created_at',
        ];
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return Newsletter::where('isSubscribed', true)->get(['id','name','email','created_at']);
    }
}
```