# How to change columns names in Excel Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I use [this library](https://laravel-excel.com/) to export data from collection to excel file. By default I et columns names as namesd of table fields.

How to replace names of colums on own?

I have own abstract class:

```
abstract class Excel
{ 
    
    abstract public function export();

    public function download()
    {
        $this->file = \Excel::create($this->filename, function ($excel) {
            $excel->sheet($this->sheetname, function ($sheet) {
                $sheet->fromArray($this->data->toArray());
            });
        })->store($this->typefile, $this->path_save);
    }

}
```

My excel file:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Library;
    
    use App\Library\Excel;
    use App\DistributorContacts;
    use App\PersonalityTraits;
    use App\Helpers\Helper;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
    
    
    class ExcelConclusions extends Excel implements WithHeadings
    {
    
    
        public $type = "_conclusions";
    
    
        public function headings(): array
        {
            return ["your", "headings", "here"];
        }
    
        public function export()
        {}
    }
```

Comment: this is a very well documented package, have you read through its documentation?

Comment: There is not section about that ,I have tried

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you include column headers when exporting Eloquent to Excel in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54245622/how-can-you-include-column-headers-when-exporting-eloquent-to-excel-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your export class use the interface headings like that:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\NameOfTable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
class NameOfExport implements FromCollection , WithHeadings{

    public function collection()
    {
        return NameOfTable::get();
    }

     public function headings():array
        {
            return [
                'NameOfFirstColumn',
                'NameOfSecondColumn,
        ....
        
            ];
        } 
}
```

You should define all the columns exported.

I have a controller ExportExcel that calls the exports defined as Exports class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Exports\nameOfExpport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

    class ExportExcel extends Controller
    {
        //
        public function functionName() {
            return Excel::download(new nameOfExpport() , 'fileName');
        }

.....
```

Comment: Should I implement interface?

Comment: I have edited my answer, please see if it's working ....

Comment: If it helped, please select this as an answer (the checkmark bellow the answer) :)

Comment: Could you provide imports?

Comment: Checkout my question please

Comment: I use that to export a report in excel with my columns names  this is what you asked ....

Comment: I have edited, hope it helps.....

Comment: Thank I try your way but always get this error: `Interface 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings' not found`

Comment: Use this:  
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings; 
in Exports class that you are using.

Comment: I have tried, no effect. I have updated question

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: What is `namespace App\Exports;`?

Comment: I still get `FatalErrorException in ExcelConclusions.php line 12:
Interface 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings' not found`

Comment: There are created all exports made by:  php artisan make:export NameOfTheExport --model=User (first class in the answer) see also https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/

Comment: I don know but this import not working

Comment: Try without using your abstract class and see if is working....

Comment: Problem is I tried import `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;` in HomeController. the same result

Comment: FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 24:
Interface 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings' not found

Comment: Maybe because you don't use namespace App\Exports;

Comment: Why if this file is placed by path `app\Library\Excel` and HomeController uses `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

Comment: I see, that path (App\Exports) was created by Laravel Excel when installed.

Comment: So whats is namespace to use to import interface in home controller?

Comment: I have also namespace App\Http\Controllers; and use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel; and use App\Exports\nameOfExport; in my controller

Comment: Interface 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings' not found

Comment: I have updated the answer for the controller that call the export.
Again, namespace App\Exports is the default used by the package ... I think there is something wrong.

Comment: No effect, I dont know why

Comment: Did you create the export by using: php artisan make:export nameOfExport --model=User ?

Comment: `Undefined type 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings'.inteleph`

Comment: Could you connect to my PC?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239987/discussion-between-alice-messis-and-radu).