# Allow laravel to filter requests based on field types

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So i have 300 different fields in my form generating from a database.These fields can be either a drop-down or text field which need to be saved in two different databases.
To get all the fields that are dropdown i will have to use

```
$request->input('name')
$request->input('email')
$request->input('username')
```

and 100 other fields.

rather than doing that and to filter requests based on input types

```
if(input_type==text){
save to this table
}
else if (input type==select){
save to this table
}
```

Comment: I have posted answer please check @Hosowu

Comment: Change field names in HTML so you can clearly distinct it on backend. Plastic explanation could seem like `dd_name` and `tt_address` for example. So you could go through foreach loop and check if key has `dd_` or `tt_` or what else.

Answer (score 0):

User laravel DB class for that.

Consider below example .

```
$data = array();
if(input_type==text){
  $data['field1'] = 'somevalue';
}
else if (input type==select){
  $data['field2'] = 'somevalue';
}
$Insert = DB::table('TABLE_NAME')->insert($data);
```

Make sure that table have detault value for fields which you are not inserting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. I am guessing you have two different `Model` class for store in the database

```
$firstTableFields = [ 'field1', 'field2', 'field3'];
$secondTableFields = [ 'field4', 'field5', 'field6'];

$firstModel = new Model($request->only($firstTableFields));
$firstModel->save();

$secondModel = new Model($request->only($secondTableFields));
$secondModel->save();
```

Comment: there are alot of fields how do i extract them from model and then pass.

Comment: and also i want to send other values to the model

Comment: This will help to get columns from a table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157270/how-to-select-all-column-name-from-a-table-in-laravel

if you want to add other values you can just add them manually before calling `->save()` on the model