# Laravel 5.8+get array of columns and rows from query

Tags: php, laravel-5

Relatively new to Laravel and trying to create a REST api that will have as a response a json that is split between rows and cols of a query

So, the code used to generate the json is:

```
$r = array(
        'cols' => array_keys(get_object_vars(Dd_hr::take(2)->get())),
        'rows' => Dd_hr::take(2)->get()
    );
return response()->json($r, 201);
```

Basically, the json should look something like:

```
{"cols":[{"id", "user_name"}],"rows":[{"710206","user"}]}
```

But in fact it looks like:

```
{"cols":[],"rows":[{"id":"710206","user_name":"user"}]}
```

Could someone help me to solve this issue?

The result of `dd(Dd_hr::take(2)->get()->toArray())`:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:27 [▼
    "rn" => "1"
    "id" => "710206"
    "user_name" => "user"
  ]
  1 => array:27 [▼
    "rn" => "2"
    "id" => "710207"
    "user_name" => "user"
  ]
]
```

Comment: **Related:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157270/how-to-select-all-column-name-from-a-table-in-laravel

Comment: I saw that earlier while searching and it's not providing what I need, sorry.. I need a way to get the columns from a query that might have 5 or 11 columns, depending on the user selection

Comment: I've updated my answer for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't find a way to do this properly so here goes the good old array_map.

This doesn't remove the "rn" key. If you want to chose the keys in the select you can, it'll even make creating the JSON easier since you'll already have the 'cols'.

```php
$res_array = Dd_hr::take(2)->get()->toArray();

$cols = array_keys($res_array[0]);

$rows = array_map(function($row){
            return array_values($row);
        }, $res_array);

return response()->json(array('cols'=>$cols, 'rows'=>$rows), 201);
```

This returns :
"{"cols":["rn","id","user_name"],"row":[["1","710206","user"],["2","710207","user"]]}"

Comment: The json looks like: {"cols":[0,1],"rows":[{"id":"710206","user_name":"user"}]}. Not the result expected..

Comment: Could you post the result of a dd(Dd_hr::take(2)->get()->toArray()) please ?