# How to show column names of multiple table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables `person` and `country`. Table `person` has 3 columns `id_person`, `name_person` and `id_country`. `country` has 2 columns `id_country` and `name_country`.

I want to show "name_person" and "name_country", just the name of column, not record. How can I get this ?

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7091984/6527256) answer.

Comment: It would be helpful to understand what you're trying to achieve. Why do you want to get the column names, if you already know them?

Comment: i want to get the name of column to create a string from it. then merge it with the record of table. Finally I have only one string. sorry for my bad english sir :)

Comment: What is the query you are trying to do?

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: ok thanks. I got it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access table columns in MySQL's information schema database:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_NAME` IN ('country', 'person')
    AND `COLUMN_NAME` LIKE 'name_%';
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT p.name_person, c.name_country FROM person AS p LEFT JOIN country as c ON (p.id_country=c.id_country)');
$fields = array_keys($result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

If you want to get the data an not only the columns names, just remove the array_keys.

```
$fields = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: that's show the records. I want to show the name of column

Comment: The first on using `array_keys` should only print the column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    $result = $db->query('SELECT person.name_person, country.name_country FROM person LEFT JOIN country ON (person.id_country=country.id_country)');

    print_r(array_keys($result));
```