# PHP MySQL inner join with same column name

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT * 
        FROM people p
        INNER JOIN job j           
        ON p.job_id = j.id
        WHERE p.id = '$id'
        ORDER BY j.id ASC");
    $maps = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
        $product = array(
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'job_id' => $row['j.id']
        )
    }
```

**table people**

`id`

**table job**

`id`

In the above code I am doing an inner join between two tables. Both tables have an a column called `id` is there a way to differentiate between the two in my `while loop`?

I have tried the above but `$row['j.id']` doesn't work and if I do `$row['id']` then it writes both `id` and `job_id` with the same value.

Comment: you need to use alias while selecting the data and best is select only which is needed instead of *.

Comment: Put an "as [column name]" on one of the columns.  That way you can specify that you want it named differently.

Comment: You can also technically access both ID values by fetching in numeric mode and referring to them via index... I wouldn't recommend it, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP & MYSQL: How to resolve ambiguous column names in JOIN operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431391/php-mysql-how-to-resolve-ambiguous-column-names-in-join-operation)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$q    = $db->query("SELECT *, j.id as jid, p.id as pid 
        FROM people p
        INNER JOIN job j           
        ON p.job_id = j.id
        WHERE p.id = '$id'
        ORDER BY j.id ASC");
$maps = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
    $product = array(
        'id'     => $row['pid'],
        'job_id' => $row['jid']
    );
}
```