# PHP & MYSQL: How to resolve ambiguous column names in subquery

Tags: php, mysql

After trying to query the following nested query

```
SELECT ur.userID, us.fullname
FROM tbl_user_recipe AS ur JOIN tbl_user_settings AS us ON ur.userID = us.userID
WHERE relationship = 'analyzed' AND userID IN 
( SELECT ux.userID
  FROM tbl_user_recipe AS ux
  WHERE ux.relationship = 'collected'
);
```

I'm getting the following, and idea why?

```
#1052 - Column 'userID' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP & MYSQL: How to resolve ambiguous column names in JOIN operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431391/php-mysql-how-to-resolve-ambiguous-column-names-in-join-operation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prefix the alias to the table here:

```
WHERE relationship = 'analyzed' AND ur.userID IN
```