# Recovers Ids from table and delete them from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I have two tables.

ticket:

```
+--------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ticket_id          | int(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ticket_user_id     | int(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ticket_status      | varchar(6)      | NO   |     | opened  |                |
| ticket_subject     | varchar(100)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ticket_message     | text            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

ticket_reply:

```
+------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ticket_reply_id        | int(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ticket_reply_ticket_id | int(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ticket_reply_showname  | varchar(40)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ticket_reply_message   | text            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`ticket_reply_ticket_id` correspond to `ticket_id` to link these 2 tables.

In PHP, I have an `$userId` and I need to delete all tickets from the ticket table of `$userId` but also to delete all replies corresponding these tickets Id.

Is it possible to dot it in one or 2 sql request or do I have to make a delete of ticket_reply for each ticket_id of `$userId` ?

Thanks?

Comment: You shouldnt name your fields with `<tablename>_<fieldname>`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza So `ticket_id` would be just `id`?

Comment: Yes, and `ticket_user_id` just `user_id`, etc. Because when you refer to a field you use notation `<tablename>.<fieldname>`, and with current format will say `<tablename>.<tablename>_<fieldname>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL foreign key constraints, cascade delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I use aliases. Don't you?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I started renaming my tables but now I have duplicates column with the same name like "id". How do you deal with it?

Comment: You shouldnt ... probably you make `ticket_id  and ticket_user_id` both `id` instead of `id, user_id`

Comment: @Strawberry of course I use alias, but this format cause unnecesary long name, isnt? Or there is a reason you would use it?

Comment: Ok aliases http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431391/php-mysql-how-to-resolve-ambiguous-column-names-in-join-operation

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I think it's basically fine. While I agree it's irritating to prefix every column with the tablename, I prefer table_id to id.

Comment: @Strawberry yes me too, but only because make JOIN more clear, but the rest of the fields is overkill.