# Codeigniter calling table database which I don't call

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my controller :
I have function like this :

```
$this->admindata->examview($a,3);
```

In model, I just have function like this :

```
function examview($examid, $examtipe){
   $this->db->select("exam_id");
   $this->db->from("mainexam");
   $query = $this->db->get()
   return $query->result();
}
```

And i got error :

```
Column 'id_group' in field list is ambiguous

SELECT `mu`.`obli`, `mu`.`id_exam_question`, `p`.`id_question`, `question`, `type_question`, `m`.`id_gabungan`, `p_parent`, `id_group` FROM (`exam`, `exam` mu) LEFT JOIN `randomexam` c ON `mu`.`id_group`= `c`.`id_question_order` LEFT JOIN `question` p ON `p`.`id_question` = `c`.`id_question` LEFT JOIN `main` m ON `m`.`id_question` = `p`.`id_question` WHERE `mu`.`id_exam` = '10' GROUP BY `mu`.`id_exam_question` ORDER BY `question_type` asc, LIMIT 0
```

I don't even have JOIN in my function. And If I delete `$this->admindata->examview($a,3)`, My error has gone. Codeigniter try to call other function I think.

Comment: your model name is `admindata`. right?

Comment: where you used `$examid, $examtipe` param in `examview` function. i thinks 2 param not needed. you can use only `function examview()` and call as same

Comment: My other functions have parameters and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nah it's tripping up on something else, a query before this one is in need of fixing. Your query here would be like

SELECT `exam_id` FROM `mainexam`;

[PHP & MYSQL: How to resolve ambiguous column names in JOIN operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431391/php-mysql-how-to-resolve-ambiguous-column-names-in-join-operation)

Try to track down the query causing the error and apply bandages.