# DataTable Model error

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datatables

This is my datatable model which combines all the tables that i need, and the console found an error in this code where VehicleNo is ambiguous.

[image]

I also need to order by ApplicationNo and distinct the ApplicationNo so that it wont duplicate other table

```
private function _get_datatables_query(){    
if($this->input->post('Status'))
{                                                           
    $this->db->where('Status', $this->input->post('Status'));
}
$this->db->select('*');
//$this->db->distinct('ApplicationNo');
$this->db->from($this->table);
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->join('user', 'user.userId = loanapplication.userId');;
$this->db->join('collateraldetails', 'collateraldetails.ApplicationNo = loanapplication.ApplicationNo');
$this->db->join('vehicleinformation', 'vehicleinformation.VehicleNo = collateraldetails.VehicleNo');
$this->db->join('loanrequest', 'loanrequest.ApplicationNo = loanapplication.ApplicationNo');
$this->db->join('loanapproval', 'loanapproval.RequestNo = loanrequest.RequestNo');
$this->db->join('paymentdetails', 'paymentdetails.ApplicationNo = loanapplication.ApplicationNo');
$this->db->join('loanpayment', 'loanpayment.PaymentId = paymentdetails.PaymentId');
//echo $this->db->last_query();exit;

$i = 0;

foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
{
    if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
    {       
        if($i===0) // first loop
        {
            // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
            $this->db->group_start(); 
            $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
        }
        else
        {

            $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
        }

        if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
            $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
    }
    $i++;
}

if(isset($_POST['ApplicationNo'])) // here order processing
{
    $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['ApplicationNo']['0']['column']], $_POST['ApplicationNo']['0']['dir']);
} 
else if(isset($this->ApplicationNo))
{

    $ApplicationNo = $this->ApplicationNo;
    $this->db->order_by(key($ApplicationNo), $ApplicationNo[key($ApplicationNo)]);
}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP & MYSQL: How to resolve ambiguous column names in JOIN operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431391/php-mysql-how-to-resolve-ambiguous-column-names-in-join-operation)

Comment: The message tells you that the error is in the WHERE clause. The ambiguous means that more than one reference to the a column named `VehicleNo` was found (among all the tables in the join), and you need to specifically reference which one you want. To do so, simply add the table you need:  \`table\`.\`VehicleNo\`

Answer (score 1):

It's ambiguous because it's confused which you are referring to, use alias in your table.

Answer (score 0):

You have column `VehicleNo` in more than one table. You joined it and don't specify column `VehicleNo` from which table, is used in where condition. That's you get this error.

You need to specify like `vehicleinformation`.`VehicleNo`. Also, you should use table alias, It's good practice.

Comment: the problem i think is that dataTable have predifined VehicleNo where clause.   $this->db->group_start(); 
            $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);

Comment: You should work around `foreach ($this->column_search as $item)` line. You should either use key pair value or multidimensional array for $item. Basic idea is to specify $item from which table. For example: If you are using key pair value format than  `foreach ($this->column_search as $table=>$item)` and  this line `$this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);` would be `$this->db->like($table.$item, $_POST['search']['value']);`