# How to sum two column from different Table in H2 Database

Tags: h2

I have two tables in database called `purchase` AND `sales`
Tables as follow

Table `purchases`

```
----------------------------
ID  PRODUCT   QTY 
----------------------------
1   APPLE     100
2   BANANA    200
3   GRAPES    150
4   AVACADO   110
```

Table `Sales`

```
----------------------------
ID  PRODUCT   QTY 
----------------------------
1   APPLE     50
2   BANANA    200
3   GRAPES    100
```

Here in the above tables i have `purchase` and `sales` i want to do subtraction from `purchases` quantity with `sales` quantity

and get the output like this

```
Output
----------------------------
ID  PRODUCT   QTY 
----------------------------
1   APPLE     50
2   BANANA    0
3   GRAPES    50
4   AVACADO   110
```

i written query but not working

```
select id, product, (purchases.qty)-(sales.qty) from purchases left join sales on purchases.id=sales.id
```

Comment: Not working, can you please explain or post the error you are getting

Comment: Can you explain what is not working?

Comment: Simply see union.

Comment: what's your problem can you explain??

Comment: it says Ambiguous column name id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP & MYSQL: How to resolve ambiguous column names in JOIN operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431391/php-mysql-how-to-resolve-ambiguous-column-names-in-join-operation)

Comment: Ambiguous column name "ID"; SQL statement:

Comment: You need to provide the table name for all columns because they are the same in the two tables.

Comment: Try select purchases.id,purchases.product ...

Comment: Hey thank you both @Shadow and @M Khalid Junaid you were right problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```
SELECT purchases.id,purchases.product, (purchases.qty - IF (sales.qty IS NULL, 0, sales.qty)) as qty FROM pruchases LEFT JOIN sales ON purchases.product = sales.product
```

Comment: hey @Max Gaurav, to be frankly i found the solution before your answered it, and next problem raised with null, and your answer fixed it cheers for that

Answer (score 0):

See all three Images your problem may be solved.

[SALES TABLE [Same as Sales Table][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZtAn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZtAn.png)

[PURCHASE TABLE [Same as Purchase Table][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lejF5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lejF5.png)

[RESULTANT IMAGE [Resultant Image With Query][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D85dT.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D85dT.png)