# Having an issue fetching the exact same column in a JOIN

Tags: php, sql

I'm fetching the column 'toggle' in a LEFT JOIN as a trigger to determine whether or not to use another column on the output side.

So I have this as an example:

```sql
SELECT *,o.toggle,t.toggle from teams t
LEFT JOIN team o
ON (joining clause)
```

Toggle either equals 1 or IS NULL.

The problem is in the output

I can't echo `$row['o.toggle']` and `$row['t.toggle']`.

It has to be `$row['toggle']`.

The second one overrides the first.  How do I differentiate those to use them?

Even assigning them variables doesn't help.  It doesn't allow me to use the reference letter o or t.

If it's NULL and NULL, that's fine.

If it's 1 and 1, that's fine too.

If it's 1 and 0, 0 wins.

If it's 0 and 1, 1 wins.

I need to be able to use o.toggle and t.toggle.

Comment: You want to use aliases. There will be a duplicate question for this but TL;DR ~ `SELECT o.toggle AS oToggle, t.toggle AS tToggle`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve ambiguous column names when retrieving results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431391/how-to-resolve-ambiguous-column-names-when-retrieving-results)

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize you could use aliases for columns too.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with the rest of your project