# php function to fetch data joining multiple tables with common field names and displaying output

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have a PHP function to fetch users data but the joined tables share common field names like `id`, `name` etc. I am using `SELECT *` here. How can I display the data.

```
function userData(){
  global $pdo;

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users
                         LEFT JOIN cities ON users.city = cities.id
                         LEFT JOIN states ON cities.state_id = states.id
                         LEFT JOIN countries ON states.country_id = countries.id
                         WHERE users.id = :id");
  $stmt-> bindValue(':id', sessionUser());
  $stmt-> execute();
  return $stmt->fetch();
}
$user = userData();
```

I want something like:

```
$user['cities.name']
$user['states.name']
```

But that doesn't work. What to do?

Comment: Column aliases are the only way. You should avoid use of `SELECT *` whenever possible anyway; this is just further incentive to do so!

Comment: You could try [PDO::FETCH_NAMED](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_NAMED)

Comment: @NigelRen I had not heard of that before, thanks! (I upvoted YCS' recent answer on the linked duplicate as well.)

Comment: If you don't want to alias your fields I think the only options are to use the ordinal value that you get with PDO::FETCH_BOTH or try PDO::FETCH_NAMED which groups the values by the column name. Either way you'll be referencing an index, ie `$user[0]` or `$user['name'][0]`.

Comment: @NigelRen and cOle2 If yours was the answer I would have accepted it. Thanks both of you. That did the task. :)

Comment: You can give an upvote to https://stackoverflow.com/a/60692300/1213708.

Comment: Hey your other question got deleted. Not sure why.
I figured out what you were after, It's not a css issue. Just add 'checked' to the input field as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give your SQL columns aliases.

```
SELECT
 `cities`.`name` as 'cities.name',
 `states`.`name` as 'states.name',
 (etc)
```

Otherwise (I believe) PHP will misunderstand and overwrite values where the keys (column names) are the same.

Comment: This is a regular approach and there are a lot of fields. I can't go name them each. I need a universal solution for this.

Comment: I don't think there is a (straightforward) way of achieving what you want. I had the same issue as you, and I wrote a complex custom class to pull in all column names (with aliases). It's one of the limitations of PHP and mySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in the fields that you want returned i.e.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users,
                         cities.name as cityName
                         states.name as stateName
                         LEFT JOIN cities ON users.city = cities.id
                         LEFT JOIN states ON cities.state_id = states.id
                         LEFT JOIN countries ON states.country_id = countries.id
                         WHERE users.id = :id");
```

Then use:

```
$user['cityName']
$user['stateName']
```

Comment: This is a regular approach and there are a lot of fields. I can't go name them each. I need a universal solution for this.

Comment: Unless you include the fields within the select statement then they wont be returned.